# Not able to open notepad using autoit with python

Tags: python, autoit

I want to open notepad and perform some task, but its not opening.
i tried this code

```
import win32com.client
autoit = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")
autoit.Run("notepad.exe")
```

notepad doesn't open but these work fine

```
autoit.Run("calc.exe")
autoit.Run("explorer.exe")
autoit.Run("regedit")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do something like [this](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/123265-unable-to-use-autoitx-with-python-on-win7x64/):

```
Open a command prompt window (cmd) as an administrator
Go to AutoItX directory (default on Windows 7 : cd C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoItX\)
Type these two commands :
regsvr32.exe AutoItX3.dll
regsvr32.exe AutoItX3_x64.dll
```

Then, try so:

```
import win32com.client
autoit = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")

#Run(program, workingdir, show_flag)
autoit.Run("notepad.exe",'',5)
```

Description of the parameters for the function `Run` you can find [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm). Integer values for parameter `show_flag` you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (5 corresponds `SW_SHOW`)

Comment: thanks, this " autoit.Run("notepad.exe",'',5) " helped, i had already registered AutoItX3.dll and AutoItX3_x64.dll